# Android C2DM Server Side

Tags: c#, java, android, android-c2dm

I just figured out how to implement android c2dm client but on the server side i have some troubles. I made search running through the internet but all the samples are too complicated for me or they are written down in python. I need some basic samples for server side in C# or java. Could you suggest anything for me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this question, and this answer.

https://github.com/Redth/C2DM-Sharp

Works a treat for me, decent code, easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#server

This basically has the required info, and the steps needed to take to send a message to the Google C2DM servers.

Basically, you're going to use C#'s URL fetching library to send a POST request to  https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send, which includes in the body of the POST the variables listed on the code.google.com page I linked to above.

I'm not going to post sample code, but if you look on google for "C# How to send POST request," you'll know HOW to send a POST.  You now know WHERE to send the POST, and you now know WHAT you need to send to the POST URL.

You just need to implement that now.